# Recyclerview data is not shown when parent container is in animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have the 2 activities to show the info, say **FirstActivity** and **SecondActivity**.

Click on **FirstActivity** item will launch **SecondActivity**.

**SecondActivity** *contains the `fragment` to show the list data* .

The data is query from the local database. 
The **SecondActivity** has the `activity` animation on launch sliding from right to left.

The issue is that when launching **SecondActivity**, the row item data is not updated until `activity` animation finished. **It's happening BELOW Android 7.0**.

[image]

I load data with CursorLoader, and shown with `recyclerview`. The data item count is right. But the list row item data is not shown until animation done.

I want it to show during animation also. **It is happening on Android 4.3, Android 6.0 Nexus devices. Not on Android 7.1.**

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No add animation solve my problem.